# Why is this expression being unsigneded?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

On x86_64 CentOS 7 GCC 4.8.5 C++11:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << ((ssize_t)1 - (size_t)5) << '\n';
}

// Output: 18446744073709551612
```

But:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << ((ssize_t)1 - (unsigned int)5) << '\n';
}

// Output: -4
```

And on i686 CentOS 6 GCC 4.8.2 C++11, they both give `4294967292` so I have to do this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << ((ssize_t)1 - (ssize_t)5) << '\n';
}

// Output: -4
```

An extremely contrived example, obviously, and I understand that I'm hitting various clauses in the integral promotion rules depending on the platform/implementation-defined type equivalences, but on a Thursday my brain can't unravel them for a rigourous assessment.

What exactly is the sequence of standard rules that leads me to these results?

Comment: what about `sizeof(ssize_t)`, `sizeof(unsigned int)` and `sizeof(size_t)` in both platforms?

Comment: Not a language lawyer myself, but IIRC, unsigned int can convert to signed long int, because the larger signed type can hold all values of the unsigned type. But if sizes are the same then unsigned wins. Don't know if that helps you finding what you need in the spec (I don't have it infront of me right now.)

Comment: Given the value you obtain (2^64-1 and 2^32-1), you probably have `sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(ssize_t) == 8 > sizeof(int) == sizeof(unsigned int) == 4` on CentOS 7, and `sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(ssize_t) == sizeof(int) == sizeof(unsigned int) == 4` on CentOS 6, so in the later case the `unsigned int` get converted to `ssize_t` (same size, unsigned win) while in the other you get the opposite result (larger size win).

Comment: @Holt Not promoted; converted.

Comment: @JulianDeclercq That is not a spelling mistake.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I see now, I apologize.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<sup>Disclaimer: I refer to paragraph 11 of clause 5 of the latest draft N4606 of C++17. The wording I quote and cite is contained in [paragraph 9 of N3337](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr#9), which is virtually identical to the C++11 standard, and in that form also in the FD of C++14, so this answer applies to these standards as well.</sup>

Assuming that `ssize_t` and `size_t` have equal rank, in your first case, [[expr]/(11.5.5)](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#11.5.5) applies:

> Otherwise, both operands shall be converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to the
>   type of the operand with signed integer type.

1 will be converted to the unsigned version of `ssize_t`, which should be  `size_t`—hence the unsigned underflow, and the value of 2<sup>`sizeof(size_t)*8`</sup>-4.

For your second case, assuming that the rank of `unsigned` is less than that of `ssize_t`, and the latter can hold all of the former's values; see [[expr]/(11.5.4)](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#11.5.4):

> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of
>   the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, the operand with unsigned integer type shall
>   be converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

I.e. `5` will be converted to `ssize_t`, and so we get the negative result. If `ssize_t` is not of greater rank than `unsigned`, we'd get 2<sup>`sizeof(unsigned)*8`</sup>-4; if instead `ssize_t` could not hold all of `unsigned`'s values, we get the negative result again, because we fall through to the aforementioned (11.5.5).